# "undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby, rest, this

```
# .              gLayer1. gLayer2  gLayer3  gLayer4. gLayer5. gLayer6. gLayer7. gLayer8. gLayer9
gameBoard = %w[oooooooo xooooooo oxoooooo ooxooooo oooxoooo ooooxooo oooooxoo ooooooxo ooooooox]

puts 'hello, welcome to eve sim'
sleep 1
puts 'this is a game, where the player has to avoid stuff, and collect candy.'
sleep 2
puts 'please use wasd to move around'
puts ' '

puts gameBoard[1]
puts gameBoard[0]
puts gameBoard[0]
puts gameBoard[0]
puts gameBoard[0]

gLayer1 = 1
gLayer2 = 0
glayer3 = 0
gLayer4 = 0
gLayer5 = 0

x_layer = 1
x_pos = 1

loop do
  move_command = gets.chomp

  if move_command == 'd'

    # \/.    \/.    \/.    \/.    \/.    \/.    \/.
    # this is the code to move the player right
    if x_layer == 1
      gLayer1 += 1

      puts gameBoard[gLayer1]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer2]
      puts gameBoard[glayer3]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer4]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer5]

      x_pos += 1

    elsif x_layer == 2
      gLayer2 += 1

      puts gameBoard[gLayer1]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer2]
      puts gameBoard[glayer3]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer4]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer5]

      x_pos += 1

    elsif x_layer == 3
      glayer3 += 1

      puts gameBoard[gLayer1]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer2]
      puts gameBoard[glayer3]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer4]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer5]

      x_pos += 1

    elsif x_layer == 4
      gLayer4 += 1

      puts gameBoard[gLayer1]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer2]
      puts gameBoard[glayer3]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer4]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer5]

      x_pos += 1

    elsif x_layer == 5
      gLayer5 += 1

      puts gameBoard[gLayer1]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer2]
      puts gameBoard[glayer3]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer4]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer5]

      x_pos += 1

    end

    if x_pos == 9
      puts 'you have died, sorry'
      sleep 2
      exit!
    end

  elsif move_command == 's'

    if x_layer == 1
      gLayer1 -= gLayer1
      gLayer2 += x_pos

      puts gameBoard[gLayer1]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer2]
      puts gameBoard[glayer3]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer4]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer5]

      x_layer += 1

    elsif x_layer == 2
      gLayer2 -= gLayer2
      gLayer3 += x_pos

      puts gameBoard[gLayer1]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer2]
      puts gameBoard[glayer3]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer4]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer5]

      x_layer += 1

    elsif x_layer == 3
      gLayer3 -= gLayer3
      gLayer4 += x_pos

      puts gameBoard[gLayer1]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer2]
      puts gameBoard[glayer3]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer4]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer5]

      x_layer += 1

    elsif x_layer == 4
      gLayer4 -= gLayer4
      gLayer5 += x_pos

      puts gameBoard[gLayer1]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer2]
      puts gameBoard[glayer3]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer4]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer5]

      x_layer += 1

    elsif x_layer == 5
      gLayer5 -= gLayer5
      gLayer6 += x_pos

      puts gameBoard[gLayer1]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer2]
      puts gameBoard[glayer3]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer4]
      puts gameBoard[gLayer5]

      x_layer += 1

      puts 'you are dead, sorry.'
      sleep 1
      exit!
    end

  elsif move_command == 'a'

  elsif move_command == 'w'

    x_layer += 1

  end
end
```

The part that comes first is fine. its just the s controller. When I go down to layer 3, it gives me that error.

I'm pretty sure is has to do with adding two negatives together, but I still don't know how that would trigger an error. I have no clue what's wrong with this code.

Please don't add anything; just explain it and fix the part that needs fixing.

Answer (score 1):

`gLayer3` has no value. Or better, its value is `nil`. Because you called it `glayer3`. So, you're practically doing `nil + something_else`. And that is `nil.+(something_else)`. And there is no `+` method for `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

In xlayer == 5 block gLayer6 is not defined and returning nil. Just in the beginning of your program set gLayer6 = 0.

Comment: My bad gLayer6 was not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `everything on Ruby are objects`. So when you call `a + b` is the same of `a.+ b`. So `+` is a method from "a".

So, if you are receiving “undefined method `+` for nil:NilClass” is because some variable on left of operator/method is nil.

To check exacly where it is happening check the line where it is happening on logs. Hope I could help you to understand your error and make things easy on next time.